# why load in jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I have this very simple code in jQuery(I am a starter), and I don't know why its not working even though I did it according to the book:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
     <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#top").load("welcome.html");
                    $("#hyber").load("spring.html");
            $("#disc").load("csi232.html");
        });
          </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="container">
        <div id="top">
        </div>
        <div id="hyber">
        </div>
        <div id="disc">
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: any console log errors ? also, do you have a welcome.html in the current directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

by this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This imports the library directly from internet. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1.you have a bug in your code you forgot to close the div of id container

2.Replace .load() with .html() so the code will be like this:

```
      <html>
      <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>  
      <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#top").html("welcome.html");
        $("#hyber").html("spring.html");
        $("#disc").html("csi232.html");
        });
          </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div id="container">
       <div id="top">
        </div>
        <div id="hyber">
        </div>
        <div id="disc">
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: you can replace  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>   with   <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> as you want :)